# Gradient of a scalar function

Tags: calculus

Is it possible for to express $$\nabla\phi(x,t)+{d^2\over dt^2}\vec v(t)$$ in the form of $$\nabla \theta(x,t)$$ for some scalar function $\theta(x,t)$? If so how might I find it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am supposing that $\nabla \phi(x,t)=(\frac{\partial\phi (x,t)}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial\phi (x,t)}{\partial x_n})$ and $v(t)=(v_1(t),...,v_n(t))$. If you define $\theta$ by $$\theta (x,t)=\phi(x,t)+x_1\frac{d^2 v_1(t)}{dt^2}+...+x_n\frac{d^2 v_n(t)}{dt^2}$$

then you have that $$\nabla \theta(x,t)=\nabla\phi(x,t)+\frac{d^2 v(t)}{dt^2}$$